# React find and get elements on object array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose

In my project I have a state object called `products`.

```
{
    "productName": "flute",
    "batches": [{
        "_id": {...},
        "batchNo": "flu1",
        "expDate": "10/2020",

    }, {
        "_id": {...},
        "batchNo": "flu2",
        "expDate": "11/2020",

    }],

}
```

mongoose schema of it is

```
productName:{
        type:String
    },
    batches:[{    
            batchNo:{
                type:String
            },
            expDate:{
                type:String
            },
}]
```

inside the batches array i want to get data only from a specific batch ID(this.props.batchID)
I tried below code but didn't work.
how can I approach it????

```
    getBatchdetails(){
         this.state.products.batches.map(function(object,i){
            console.log(object.batchNo);
            if(object._id==this.props.obj.batchID){
                console.log(object.batchNo);

                return object.batchNo;
            }
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {this.state.products.productName}
                </td>
                <td>
                   {this.getBatchdetails}
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for that purpose. I made up a fake `batchID` but you can change to your value.

Try the following:

```js
const batchID = 'id002';
const products = {
    "productName": "flute",
    "batches": [{
        "_id": 'id001',
        "batchNo": "flu1",
        "expDate": "10/2020",

    }, {
        "_id": 'id002',
        "batchNo": "flu2",
        "expDate": "11/2020",

    }],

};

const result = products.batches.find(e => e._id === batchID);

console.log(result);
console.log(result.batchNo); // or you can return a specific property
```

I hope this helps!